# Add two textures on the same mesh WEBGL

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, webgl, textures

I need to add two textures on the same mesh. I have an octahedron with a texture and I want to add a second texture above it. How can I achieve this? The first texture is appearing but the second one not. I created two different textures at my .js file and enabled 2 different texture slots for both of them. I did bind the textures and pass the textures slots as a uniform in the fragment shader. I think that my HTML file is wrong so I am attaching the code of the HTML file.

```
<script id="shader-fs" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
     precision mediump float;

     varying vec2 vTextureCoord;
     varying vec3 vLightWeighting;

     uniform sampler2D uSampler; 
     uniform sampler2D uSampler1;

     void main(void) {
         vec3 c;
         vec4 textureColor = texture2D(uSampler, vec2(vTextureCoord.s, vTextureCoord.t));
         vec4 textureColor1 = texture2D(uSampler1, vec2(vTextureCoord.s, vTextureCoord.t));           

        c = textureColor.rgb * textureColor.a + textureColor1.rgb * textureColor1.a * (1.0 - textureColor.a);
        gl_FragColor= vec4(c, 1.0);
     }
    </script>

    <script id="shader-vs" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
     attribute vec3 aVertexPosition;
     attribute vec3 aVertexNormal;
     attribute vec2 aTextureCoord; 

     uniform mat4 uMVMatrix;
     uniform mat4 uPMatrix;
     uniform mat3 uNMatrix;

     uniform vec3 uLightingDirection;
     uniform vec3 uDirectionalColor;

     varying vec2 vTextureCoord;
     varying vec3 vLightWeighting;

     void main(void) {
         gl_Position = uPMatrix * uMVMatrix * vec4(aVertexPosition, 0.5);
         vTextureCoord = aTextureCoord; 

         vec3 transformedNormal = uNMatrix * aVertexNormal; 
         float directionalLightWeighting = max(dot(transformedNormal, uLightingDirection), 0.0);
         vLightWeighting = uDirectionalColor * directionalLightWeighting;
     }
    </script>
```

Comment: Debug the shader, add `gl_FragColor = textureColor;` to the end of your fragment shader. Do you see the first texture? If yes then change to  `gl_FragColor = textureColor1;`. Do you see the second texture? If that doesn't work then you're not setting up the textures correctly. You haven't posted your setup code so no one can tell

Comment: I fixed everything and now both of the textures are appearing all over my mesh. I am trying to understand how can I add the texture only to specific pixels/points. For example if I have a triangle I would like to put the first texture on it all over but the second one only to the two points. So near to the two points the second texture will be more 'bold' but at the center will not. Like shading... and at the third there will not be trace of the second texture.

Comment: pass in a per vertex mix value, pass that to your fragment shader, do `color = mix(colorFromTexture1, colorFromTexture2, mixValue)`